# How do i get mocha's before() hook to work properly?

Tags: hardhat, mocha, test

This is the test code im trying to run:

```
const {expect} = require("chai");
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {SignerWithAddress} = require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers");
const {utils, Contract} = require("ethers");
const baseTokenURI = "ipfs://QmUvAWoQ4STuqPLD75ErYxmeSkFu7cdQ8gZWnFF7nJFV7u/";


describe("nft-collectible-contract", () => {
        let contract;

        before(async () => {
                const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
                const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTCollectible");
                let contract = await contractFactory.deploy(baseTokenURI);
                await contract.deployed();
        });
        it("Mints an nft from the contract", async () =>{
                const price = await contract.PRICE();
                expect(await contract.mintNFTs(1, {value: price}));

        });

});
```

I have used before() in truffle without a problem before now. I'm currently building this project using hardhat but whenever I try to run this test script it says 'undefined reference to contract'. I'm guessing that the before hook is not executing like it should therefore 'contract' is not in the global namespace like it should be. When i remove the 'before' and just use an 'it' only, everything works fine. However I have more tests to write and rewriting that first bit each time will take too much time and the code will be messy.

Is the syntax for my code ok? does anyone know why before() is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you two variables with the same name in different scopes

```
describe("nft-collectible-contract", () => {
    // .. first variable
    let contract;

    before(async () => {
            // ... second variable
            let contract = await contractFactory.deploy(baseTokenURI);
            await contract.deployed();
            // ... second variables goes out of scope at the exit of the arrow function
    });
```

The fix is easy, remove `let` in the assignment

```
    before(async () => {
            contract = await contractFactory.deploy(baseTokenURI);
    });
```

Comment: thank you Ismael. Was up last night trying to figure out what was wrong, kinda embarrassing that its something this simple.